Protected routes in React native and expo router
Im trying to create protected routes in my React Native app that is also build using expo and its new routing using files. In my /app/(app)/_layout.tsx file Im indexing Slot if the users JWT token is valid. My problem is that this code runs only one time at the launch of the application and no when the user changes the screen - I have added simple redirection button to sign in screen to check if it validates the token correctly and make the user stay on the signin page. Turns out it didn't. Yes it does correctly check the token validity but only at launch as I said and not when I want to change the screens. Why is this happening and what is the correct way to handle protected routes in new expo routing.
const Root = () => {
  const [isValidToken, setIsValidToken] = useState<boolean | null>(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const verifyToken = async () => {
      const isValid = await checkTokenValidity();
      setIsValidToken(isValid);
    };

    verifyToken();
  }, [router]);

  if (isValidToken === null) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!isValidToken) {
    return <Redirect href="/sign-in" />;
  }

  return <Slot />;
};

My util
 interface JWTPayload {
      exp: number;
    }
    
    export const checkTokenValidity = async () => {
      const token = await getToken();
    
      if (!token) {
        return false;
      }
    
      const decoded: JWTPayload = jwtDecode(token);
    
      const currentTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
      if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
        return false;
      }
    
      return true;
    };

